# Ubuntu 12.04.3 64 bit with Nemo 2.0.x no thumbnails

Tags: cinnamon, thumbnails, nemo

I have strange problem with thumbnails in my Ubuntu machine.

I was using Ubuntu with Cinnamon 1.8 from stable ppa and it was good but then Cinnamon 2.0 came out with some broken packages uploaded to stable ppa nad things gone wrong...
Anyway after few updates Cinnamon started to work normaly except Nemo - there are no thumbnails at all, only icons.

I heve tried purging /.cache/thumbnails and .thumbnails folders but this doesn't work.
Next I have changed permissions for those folders - that didn't helped either.
Then I've set Nemo as default file manager and desktop handler but with no result.

What is weird - when I start Nautilus and open some folder with images then close it and open same folder with Nemo thumbnails appears but when I clean thumbnails directories there are no thumbnails again.

It would be great if someone have some solution for this annoying Nemo behavior because I  really don't want to resign from Cinnamon.

p.s.
I have set preview options in Nemo for Always and no bigger files than 4GB so that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

In your home directory:

remove the subdirectory `.thumbnails`

set link

```
ln -s .cache/thumbnails .thumbnails
```